# Capturing GPS coords in EXIF header for JPEGs with ArcPad ImageBox control?

Tags: gps, arcpad, jpg, exif

Problem with capturing GPS locations in EXIF header for JPEG photo using Esri's ArcPad and its ImageBox control.

I have customized forms for ArcPad.  I have added three ImageBox controls to a form and kept the Picture page.  If I take a photo via the Picture page, ArcPad writes EXIF data to the JPEG file (including date, time and GPS coordinates).

If I take a photo via an ImageBox control on the same form for the same feature, ArcPad does not write any EXIF data to the JPEG.  Both methods fire up the same ArcPadCamera.exe program.

Has anyone worked out how to use ArcPad's ImageBox control to force EXIF data to be written to the JPEG file?  ImageBoxes are more convenient for my users than  using the Picture page.

Esri has more or less said:

> it just doesn't do it